# Decorator Design Pattern - Not extending object behavior

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, decorator

I am learning more about design patterns and I am trying to implement the Decorator pattern. I want to extend a computer object to add a string to the end of a description for each new component. This is Unity/C# adaptation from a java example in the Design Patterns For Dummies book.

```
public class Computer {
    public Computer(){}

    public string Description(){
        return "Computer";
    }
}
```

This is the decorator component that each component will inherit from:

```
public abstract class ComponentDecorator : Computer {
    new public abstract string Description();
}
```

Here are two component classes Monitor and Disk that can decorate the computer class.

```
public class Monitor : ComponentDecorator {
    Computer computer;

    public Monitor(Computer c){
        this.computer = c;
    }

    public override string Description(){
        return computer.Description () + " and a Monitor";
    }

}

public class Disk : ComponentDecorator {
    Computer computer;

    public Disk(Computer c){
        this.computer = c;
    }

    public override string Description(){
        return computer.Description () + " and a Disk";
    }
}
```

Below is the Start method:

```
   void Start(){

        Computer computer = new Computer ();

        computer = new Disk (computer);
        computer = new Monitor (computer);

        print("You have a " + computer.Description () + ".");
    }
```

My Expected output is : "You have a Computer and a Monitor and a Disk."

The Actual output is : "You have a Computer."

Shouldn't computer now be calling the description method as if it were the Monitor description method? How could this be modified to get the expected output?

Comment: Your `ComponentDecorator` is all wrong - Most notably, you've had to use `new` in order to re-add an abstract version of `Description`. The compiler was warning you that adding `new` would cause the problem you've reported here.

Comment: `new` doesn't concatenate objects, it creates new ones and replaces the existing one.

Comment: You'd have to decorate twice in your example as well. IMHO the decorator pattern may not be the best solution for the task you provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a decorator by having both the class you are decorating and the decorator class have the same abstraction (interface or abstract class). The below code shows using the abstract class. The Device class I added here, is the abstraction for both the decorator class and the decorating class.

```
public abstract class Device
{
    public abstract string Description();
}


public class Computer : Device
{
    public Computer() { }

    public override string Description()
    {
        return "Computer";
    }
}


public class Monitor : Device
{
    Device device;
    public Monitor(Device c)
    {            this.device = c;
    }

    public override string Description()
    {
        return device.Description() + " and a Monitor";
    }

}

public class Disk : Device
{
    Device device;

    public Disk(Device c)
    {
        this.device = c;
    }

    public override string Description()
    {
        return device.Description() + " and a Disk";
    }
}
```

You don't need an abstraction of the decorator class unless you want all your decorators to implement any specific method.

Comment: So to clarify, If I am not implementing any specific method then I could actually remove the `ComponentDecorator` class altogether and just have `Monitor` and `Disk` inherit from `Computer`.

Otherwise, creating an abstract class `Device` would require that I instantiate my computer like:
 `Device computer = new Computer();` 
as opposed to just
`Computer computer = new Computer();`

Isn't `Device` serving as an abstract decorator class in your example? Perhaps I am confusing myself more.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. In the above example, you can remove the `Device` class and make the `Description()` method of `Computer` class as `virtual` and inherit the `Monitor` and `Disk` classes from `Computer` class. You can tweak a design pattern as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Your implemantation has missing points. http://www.dofactory.com/net/decorator-design-pattern has same good explanation and UML diagram. I implement your case like that:

```
public abstract class ComputerParts
{
    public abstract string Description();
}

public class Computer : ComputerParts
{
    public Computer()
        {
        }

    public override string Description()
        {
            return "Computer";
        }
}

public abstract class ComponentDecorator : ComputerParts
{
    public abstract void ExtraMethod();
}

public class Disk : ComponentDecorator
{
    ComputerParts computerParts;

    public Disk(ComputerParts c)
        {
            this.computerParts = c;
        }

    public override string Description()
        {
            return computerParts.Description() + " and a Disk";
        }

    public override void ExtraMethod()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
}

public class Monitor : ComponentDecorator
{
    ComputerParts computerParts;

    public Monitor(ComputerParts c)
        {
            this.computerParts = c;
        }

    public override string Description()
        {
            return computerParts.Description() + " and a Monitor";
        }

    public override void ExtraMethod()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers without some explanation about what you changed and how it works.